# How to use request to login and get cookie in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, request

I want to use request module to login and get session.
This is my code

```
var request = require('request');
var cookie;
var headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'accept': 'application/json'
};

var form = {
    'email': 'MY_EMAIL',
    'password': 'MY_PASSWORD'
};

request.post({url: 'http://website/login', body: JSON.stringify(form), headers: headers}, function(err, res, body){
    if(err) console.log('login error');

    // get cookie
    var setCookie = res.headers['set-cookie'];
    cookie = setCookie[0].split(' ')[0] + ' ' + setCookie[1].split(' ')[0];

    console.log('login success');
});
```

After I get the cookie, I put the cookie in headers and I can do something else which need auth.

```
var headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'cookie': cookie
}

request.get({url: 'http://website/somethingElse', headers: headers}, function(err, res, body){

    console.log(body);

});
```

If I use request cookie jar like this.

```
var request = require('request').defaults({jar: true});

var jar = request.jar();
var headers = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'accept': 'application/json'
};

var form = {
    'email': 'MY_EMAIL',
    'password': 'MY_PASSWORD'
};

request.post({url: 'http://website/login', jar: jar, body: JSON.stringify(form), headers: headers}, function(err, res, body){
    if(err) console.log('login error');

    console.log(jar);

    console.log('login success');
});
```

I can get the cookies in jar, but I can not use jar to do other things.

```
var headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'accept': 'application/json'
}

request.get({url: 'http://website/somethingElse', jar: jar, headers: headers}, function(err, res, body){

    // I am redirected to the login page.
    // It seems that I haven't login
    console.log(body);
});
```

I login the website and get the cookie successfully, but I can't use the cookies to do something which need login. I will be redirected to the login page and asked to login again. How to solve it?

Comment: the time when you hit `http://website/somethingElse` , do you have `jar` values ? I meant that are you making sure that second request executes after the completion of first request.

Comment: Yes, I output jar and ensure that there are cookies in jar.